# I created a dictionary, m={1: 2, (2, 3): (22, 23)}. I tried this m[#]=45, what happens?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

[check img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Itb.png)

Need an explanation of what's happening when I tried m[#].

Comment: please copy&paste the code. don't use images

Comment: Python interprets the **#** symbol as a comment and it's waiting for you to finish the statement

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "#" is used to comment your code so basically when you call # next caracteres is commented like : me[#i'm in the commented code and "[" was never closed ]

Comment: Hi! This answer explains what happened, but would be more complete, in my opinion, if it suggested (1) A correct use of comments, such as `m[7] = 42 # The answer to the big question`, and (2) A correct use of `'#'` as a character, such as `m['#'] = 45`

Comment: Also perhaps the explanation would be easier to understand if you showed how to continue on the next line: `>>> m[#hello <linebreak>
    ... 3] = 12`

Comment: Hi, yeah I agree with you :), thx for completed the answer

Answer (score 0):

> ```py
> m[#]=45
> ```

As you can see, everything after the `#` [is commented](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/3-comments-literals/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20any%20line%20of,when%20the%20program%20is%20run.); so, what you were actually trying to have executed was <kbd>**`m[`**</kbd> which **isn't valid syntax**.

You could instead have

```py
m['#'] = 45
```

since it will not get treated as a comment if it's within a string.